# Create a UIView with leading / trailing faded edges

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cagradientlayer

I have a `UIView` that I would like to apply a fade / gradient too. I'd like this to appear only on the edges, the effect I am trying to create is

[image: gradient example]

The grey line at the top of the image. Grey in the middle and both edges are faded to white.

I have tried something like this

```
  func render(content: FeedItem) {
        print(content.item.externalId)

//        rowSeperatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.usingHex("f2f2f2")
        iconContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.usingHex("3bac58")


        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = rowSeperatorView.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.white.cgColor,
            UIColor.usingHex("f2f2f2").cgColor,
            UIColor.white.cgColor,
        ]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.5,1]

        rowSeperatorView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)




        iconContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        iconContainerView.clipsToBounds = true
        iconContainerView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMaxXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    }
```

But cannot seem to achieve this result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, try adding a `startPoint` and `endPoint` and then play with the locations property.

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = rowSeperatorView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.usingHex("f2f2f2").cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]

    gradient.locations = [0, 0.4, 0.6]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)

    rowSeperatorView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```